# Trying to upload photo in Codeigniter - not finding my upload folder - ideas why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload profile pics during a registration process with CI ($me !== 'experienced' )

Here is my method ... nothing strange

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = base_url('/upload_pic/');
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() )
    {
        $data['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors() . $config['upload_path'];
        $this->load->view('profile_photo_view', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['message'] = $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

.. but it is failing.  As you can see, I have the upload path passing to my fail page for display, and this is what it is showing..

```
The upload path does not appear to be valid. 
http://localhost:8888/MY_SITE/upload_pic
```

That *is* where my upload folder is.  And I have full 777 permissions on it..

.. any idea what could be wrong?  And will trailing slashes always be stripped like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base_url` will give you...wait for it...a URL :)

You need a **path** for uploads.

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/full/path/to/upload_pic/';
```

or you can use relative paths:

```
$config['upload_path'] = '../upload_pic';
```

but you have to give it a path, not a URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I assumed they were fairly interchangeable.  For ex, in CSS/HTML both will work.  I always assumed that "www.WEBROOT.com/mystuff" was the same as "/mystuff" (from webroot).  I guess it's just that CI is expecting to see a path format, though.  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: It's not CI...that's just the way computers work. When you are adding/deleting/moving files on a computer, the application needs to know where to move them. Moving or uploading a file has nothing to do with the **WEB**server apart from the webserver being the interface. General rule is if you are doing something directly with a file (include, read, write, move, create) you need the PATH; if you are requesting a resource that the web server will use (css, js, html) you can use a URL. Cheers!

Comment: Also: 'assumed that "www.WEBROOT.com/mystuff" was the same as "/mystuff" (from webroot)'. Not when working with something that needs a PATH. /mystuff will tell the application to look at the root of the server for a folder called mystuff. You could do ./mystuff which tells the app to look in the current directory for a folder called mystuff.

Comment: Thx for extra info. But AARG. Added twist is I am running MAMP, so folder structure is 'MAMP/htdocs/this_CI_project". I echoed "dirname(__FILE__)" from the script and got "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/this_CI_project/application/controllers" (my first MVC and first CI.. I just wasn't sure "where" things were being called). So it's called from controllers/. My "upload_pic" folder is in the "top" of the CI install.. "this_CI_project/upload_pic/". I tried "../../upload_pic", "../upload_pic", "/upload_pic", and "/this_CI_project/upload_pic".. all give "invalid path". Trblshoot ideas?

Comment: Try ./upload_pic with 1 period. Also, Mamp has a control panel where you can set the document root. Check that.

Comment: *Now looking in stunned silent awe at the MAMP preference panel.*  Well this is freeking great.  I was always having to futz with that "one extra folder level" away from webroot on everything.  I shall bake a cake and eat it in your honour.

Answer (score 1):

As @stormdrain pointed out, `base_url()` is there to get the URL, not a filesystem path. Try:

```
$config['upload_path'] = dirname(FCPATH) . '/upload_pic/';
```

Comment: Thx.  Points for the dirname() tip.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$config['upload_path'] = base_url() . '/upload_pic/';
```

or inside index.php append this

```
define('UPLOADS', 'upload_pic');
```

then set config to

```
$config['upload_path'] = UPLOADS;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote you for suggesting base_url(). As stormdrain pointed out above, base_url() will give a URL which will not work here.  A path is needed.